python dictionary update add
I am not able to update the dictionary in python
with open ('people.csv','r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    with open('new_people.csv', 'w',newline='') as new_file:
        fieldnames = ['Id','FirstName','LastName','MiddleName']
        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter (new_file, fieldnames=fieldnames, extrasaction = 'ignore',delimiter =',')
        csv_writer.writeheader()

        for line in csv_reader:
            line['Email'] = 'null'
            
            csv_writer.writerow(line)

when I open the new_people.csv I only see the ID, F/L/M names, but not the email column. please help
I tried to add the email key to the line before writing out the file

Can you [edit] your question to include some sample data so we can have a [mre]?

The issue is probably because the DictWriter class does not include columns that are not specified in the fieldnames parameter.
Try doing this, perhaps to fieldnames:
fieldnames = ['Id', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'MiddleName', 'Email']     


Welcome to SO, keep rocking!
